# Error while Parsing json into scala case class

Tags: java, scala, jackson, case-class

In my spring(mvc) web application, I am using `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` in my scala code to map my json to scala objects using case classes. My Json String is an array of json objects objects. so I am using:

```
val user = mapper.readValue(myJson, classOf[List[MyClass]])
```

This line throws an error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of scala.collection.immutable.List, problem: abstract types
>   can only be instantiated with additional type inform

Am I using it right or is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the Java type erasure. `classOf[List[MyClass]]` at runtime is the same as `classOf[List[_]]`. That is why Jackson cannot know, which types of the elements to create.

Luckily Jackson does support parsing with the `JavaType`, which describes the types themselves.

Here a simple sample in Java:

```
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, MyClass.class);
mapper.readValue(myJson, type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of type erasure, the parameterized type of the List is lost at runtime.

Instead, use the [Scala module for Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) and you can simply do:

```
mapper.readValue(myJson, new TypeReference[List[MyClass]])
```

So long as the Scala module has been registered - this means a Scala List will be created.